# Open, save and extract text PDFs from links in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf, hyperlink

I would like to iterate through PDF links saved in python dataframe. The goal is to open the PDF links, save the PDFs and extract text from them, then save the text from each corresponding link in a new column.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
    URL
0   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/RFA-WATIH-1295_Senegal-RMNCAH-Activity_English-Version.pdf
1   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/RFA-WATIH-1295_Activit%C3%A9-RMNCAH-S%C3%A9n%C3%A9gal_Version-Fran%C3%A7aise.pdf
2   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Attachment-2_Full-Application-Template_Senegal-RMNCAH-Activity_English-Version.docx
3   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Pi%C3%A8ce-Jointe-2_Mod%C3%A8le-de-Demande-Complet_Activit%C3%A9-RMNCAH-S%C3%A9n%C3%A9gal_Version-Fran%C3%A7aise.docx
4   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Attachment-3_Trade-Hub-Performance-Indicators-Table.xlsx
5   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/Attachment-10_Project-Budget-Template-RMNCAH.xlsx
6   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Senegal-Health-RFA-Webinar-QA.pdf
7   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/APS-WATIH-1021_Catalytic-Business-Concepts-Round-2.pdf
8   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/APS-WATIH-1021_Concepts-d%E2%80%99Affaires-Catalytiques-2ieme-Tour.pdf
9   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/APS-WATIH-1247_Research-Development-Round-2.pdf
```

I was able to do that for one link but not for the whole dataframe

```
import urllib.request
pdf_link = "https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/RFA-WATIH-1295_Senegal-RMNCAH-Activity_English-Version.pdf"

def download_file(download_url, filename):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url)    
    file = open(filename + ".pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()
 
download_file(pdf_link, "Test")

#Code to extract text from PDF 

import textract
text = textract.process("/Users/fze/Dropbox (LCG Team)/LCG Folder (1)/BD Scan Automation/Python codes/Test.PDF")
print(text)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import urllib.request
import textract

def download_file(download_url, filename):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url)    
    file = open(filename + ".pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()

df['Text']=''

for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    pdf_link=df.iloc[i,0]
    download_file(pdf_link, f"pdf_{i}")
    text = textract.process(f"/Users/fze/Dropbox (LCG Team)/LCG Folder (1)/BD Scan Automation/Python codes/pdf_{i}.PDF")
    df['Text'][i]=text
```

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch !!! but I get the following error: ShellError: The command `pdf2txt.py /Users/fatimazahraelmansouri/pdf_2.PDF` failed with exit code 1
------------- stdout -------------
b''------------- stderr ------------- Any ideas why ?

Comment: I think I figured it out ! the third link is a docx not a pdf ! Any ideas how to extract text from a docx doc ? Thanks again !!! you're extremely helpful

Comment: A docs is already a text document so it should be easy. Check https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

Comment: Thanks ! this helped me tremendously advance in a very import professional project. Very grateful for people willing to help like yourself ! you're the real OG !!

Comment: Could you please solve this problem as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395489/search-specific-words-in-pdf-and-return-only-pdf-link-where-words-were-found-py