# Search specific words in pdf and return only pdf link where words were found (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, pdf, search, hyperlink

I am trying to search for multiple words in many PDFs. Links to these PDFs are saved in a dataframe. The goal is for python to return a text stating "The words are located in *pdf link*"). Here is the code I have so far: (FYI g7 is the name of the dataframe where the links are saved).The issue here is that the code returns the same link multiple times for every time the word is found.

The dataframe (named g7) looks like this:

```
    URL
0   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/RFA-WATIH-1295_Senegal-RMNCAH-Activity_English-Version.pdf
1   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/RFA-WATIH-1295_Activit%C3%A9-RMNCAH-S%C3%A9n%C3%A9gal_Version-Fran%C3%A7aise.pdf
2   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Senegal-Health-RFA-Webinar-QA.pdf
3   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/APS-WATIH-1021_Catalytic-Business-Concepts-Round-2.pdf
4   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/APS-WATIH-1021_Concepts-d%E2%80%99Affaires-Catalytiques-2ieme-Tour.pdf
5   https://westafricatradehub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/APS-WATIH-1247_Research-Development-Round-2.pdf
```

The code is as follows:

```
import glob
import pathlib
import PyPDF2
import re
import os
for i in range(g7.shape[0]):
    pdf_link=g7.iloc[i,0]
    download_file(pdf_link, f"pdf_{i}")
    text = textract.process(f"/Users/fze/pdf_{i}.PDF")        
    # open the pdf file
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f"/Users/fze/pdf_{i}.PDF") 
    all_files = glob.glob('/Users/fze/*.pdf') #User input: give path to your downloads folder file path
    latest_pdf_path = max(all_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    
    path = pathlib.PurePath(latest_pdf_path)
    latest_pdf_name=path.name
    print(latest_pdf_name)
    
    # get number of pages
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()    
    # define keyterms
    search_word = 'organization'
    # extract text and do the search
    for i in range(0, NumPages):
            page = object.getPage(i)
            text = page.extractText()
            search_text = text.lower().split()
            for word in search_text:
                if search_word in word:
                    print("The word '{}' was found in '{}'".format(search_word,pdf_link))
```

Thank you !

Comment: Why do you not look into the "text" returned by textract?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @kubatucka Ideally I would like to filter for words directly in the dataframe but I couldn't add the text in the next column. The goal is to filter for only the links that contain those specific keywords and only keep those in the dataframe.